# Model.evaluate returns 0 loss when using custom model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use my own train step in with Keras by creating a class that inherits from Model. It seems that the training works correctly but the evaluate function always returns 0 on the loss even if I send to it the train data, which have a big loss value during the training.
I can't share my code but was able to reproduce using the example form the Keras api in https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/ I changed the Dense layer to have 2 units instead of one, and made its activation to sigmoid.

The code:

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="loss")
# mae_metric = keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError(name="mae")

class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute our own loss
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result(), "mae": self.compiled_metrics.metrics[0].result()}

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        # We list our `Metric` objects here so that `reset_states()` can be
        # called automatically at the start of each epoch
        # or at the start of `evaluate()`.
        # If you don't implement this property, you have to call
        # `reset_states()` yourself at the time of your choosing.
        return [loss_tracker] + self.compiled_metrics.metrics


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Construct an instance of CustomModel
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32,))
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(inputs)
    model = CustomModel(inputs, outputs)

    # We don't passs a loss or metrics here.
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

    # Just use `fit` as usual -- you can use callbacks, etc.
    x = np.random.random((1000, 32))
    y = np.random.random((1000, 1))
    model.fit(x, y, epochs=5)
    print(model.evaluate(x, y, return_dict=True))
    x = np.random.random((1000, 32))
    y = np.random.random((1000, 1))
    print(model.evaluate(x, y, return_dict=True))
```

I try to run evaluate on the original train data as well on some random data and both return 0 on the loss and MAE.

The output:
Epoch 1/5<c
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 708us/step - loss: 0.1133 - mae: 0.1193
Epoch 2/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 688us/step - loss: 0.0962 - mae: 0.1000
Epoch 3/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 677us/step - loss: 0.0926 - mae: 0.0915
Epoch 4/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 740us/step - loss: 0.0922 - mae: 0.0872
Epoch 5/5
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 708us/step - loss: 0.0912 - mae: 0.0938
Evaluations:
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0916
{'loss': 0.0, 'mean_squared_error': 0.09163134545087814}
32/32 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - mean_squared_error: 0.0894
{'loss': 0.0, 'mean_squared_error': 0.08940737694501877}

The first evaluation is on the training data and returns 0 although in the training it isn't 0 and also the random data returns 0 - no way it is really 0.

Any ideas what might cause this problem? Or how to solve this except for overriding myself the eval method?

**Edit:**
After M.Innat response I changed the model to use the compiled loss and metrics now the metrics work, the compiled loss still doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you manually use the loss and metrics function in the `train_step` (not in the `.compile`) for the training set, you should also do the same for the validation set or by defining the `test_step` in the custom model in order to get the loss score and metrics score. Add the following function to your custom model.

```
    def test_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data
        x, y = data
        # Compute predictions
        y_pred = self(x, training=False)
        loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)
        
        # Compute our own metrics
        loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        mae_metric.update_state(y, y_pred)
        return {"loss": loss_tracker.result(), "mae": mae_metric.result()}
```

Comment: Thaks for the help. I fixed the code to use compiled loss and metrics. still doesn't work for the loss.
Will probably use your solution anyway because it seems to be the easy enough.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? If you manually use loss and metrics in your custom fit, you should do both for the training step and test step, otherwise, if you define them in `.compile`, then in custom fit, you can simply do `self.compiled_..` as described in the document.

Answer (score 1):

I found what caused the problem in the example. It is the usage of a custom loss tracker and overriding the metrics function.
Actually if you use compiled loss Keras will track it by itself in the `self.compiled_loss.metrics`.

The problem was when using a custom loss I had to override the metrics function to get a correct result and then the test_step didn't use collect the loss correctly.

The code that does work without overriding the test_step function:

```
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import tensorflow as tf

class CustomModel(keras.Model):
    def train_step(self, data):
        x, y = data

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            y_pred = self(x, training=True)  # Forward pass
            # Compute our own loss
            loss = self.compiled_loss(y, y_pred)

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Compute our own metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred)
        return {"loss": self.compiled_loss.metrics[0].result(), "mae": self.compiled_metrics.metrics[0].result()}
```